# how to create multidimensionnal array in lua with lau C api

Tags: lua, lua-api

I have an inquiry about the binding between lua and c languages.

lua usage example)

```
a[1].b.c[1].d = 1
a[1].b.c[2].d = 2
a[2].b.c[1].d = 3
a[2].b.c[2].d = 4
```

I am wondering how to create this with lua C api.
This is the code I used in C

```
    lua_createtable(L, 2, 0);
lua_pushnumber(L, 1);
{
    lua_createtable(L, 0, 1);
    {
        lua_newtable(L);
        lua_pushnumber(L, 1);
        {
            lua_pushnumber(L, 49);
            lua_setfield(L, -2, "d");
            lua_settable(L, -3);
        }
        lua_pushnumber(L, 2);
        {
            lua_pushstring(L, "old");
            lua_setfield(L, -2, "d");
            lua_settable(L, -3);
        }
        lua_setfield(L, -2, "c");
    }
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "b");
}
lua_pushnumber(L, 2);
{
    lua_createtable(L, 0, 1);
    {
        lua_newtable(L);
        lua_pushnumber(L, 1);
        {
            lua_pushnumber(L, 49);
            lua_setfield(L, -2, "d");
            lua_settable(L, -3);
        }
        lua_pushnumber(L, 2);
        {
            lua_pushstring(L, "old");
            lua_setfield(L, -2, "d");
            lua_settable(L, -3);
        }
        lua_setfield(L, -2, "c");
    }
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "b");
}
lua_setglobal(L, "a");
```

By the way
PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (attempt to index a number value)
I got an error like this

Thank you so much for telling me this.

Comment: Why are you doing `lua_pushnumber` after every `lua_newtable`? Also, why are you combining `lua_setfield` and `lua_settable` like that? Maybe you could add some comments to your code to clarify, otherwise it's just very hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

```c
lua_createtable(L, 2, 0); // Stack: {}
lua_pushnumber(L, 1); // Stack: {}, 1
{
    lua_createtable(L, 0, 1); // Stack: {}, 1, {}
    {
        lua_newtable(L); // Stack: {}, 1, {}, {}
        lua_pushnumber(L, 1); // Stack: {}, 1, {}, {}, 1
        {
            lua_pushnumber(L, 49); // Stack: {}, 1, {}, {}, 1, 49
            lua_setfield(L, -2, "d"); // !!!!!!!
            // You currently have two numbers at the top of the stack.
            // the index -2 thus points to the number 1
            // Trying to lua_setfield on that index fails because it expects
            // a table but finds an integer instead.
            lua_settable(L, -3);
            // ...
        }
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

What should I do to do it like lua code in the question?
Thank you for showing me an example.
I've only been in contact with lua for two weeks, so I don't know well, so please understand.

Comment: You're generally doing it right, but you were indexing the wrong items on the stack. It's easier if you start with a simple table, compile, see if it works and then add complexity little by little so when it breaks you know where :D @P.Kwon

Comment: a[1].b.c.d = 1
Expressing this way was a success.
By the way, I do not know how to express a[1].b.c[1].d = 1 like this.
How can we express a[1].b.c[1].d = 1?
It's really urgent. Can I see an example?